# IsNumeric true but should be false

Tags: excel, vba

consider that numberString$ is    "1st (3) Name..."  and in my code support$ is "1s" which is correct.  NumericCheck should be false but i always get true !   Where is the mistake ?

```
numbertring$ = Worksheet1.Cells(i, 1)
support$ = Left$(numbertring$, 2)

numericCheck = IsNumeric(Val(support$))
```

Thx in advance for your help

Comment: You're taking the Value of support$ as your check, which will be TRUE as it pulls the numbers from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run `support$` through `Val` before checking if it is numeric. [The definition of `Val`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/val.php) is:

> the VAL function accepts a string as input and returns the numbers found in that string.

The following illustrates how your code is being interpreted:

```
IsNumeric(Val(support$))
IsNumeric(Val("1s"))
IsNumeric(1)
```

So it should be clear now why `numericCheck` is true, not false :)

Comment: Thx, that was the mistake ... i put now numericCheck = isNumeric(support$) and it works perfectly.